# Monitoring application-specific metrics using JMX and Hyperic

Tags: java, monitoring, jmx

My webapp exposes some application-specific metrics (think "orders placed") via JMX, which I'd like to monitor using [Hyperic HQ](http://www.hyperic.com) (open source edition).

According to the [Hyperic Inventory Model](http://support.hyperic.com/display/DOC/HQ+Inventory+and+Access+Model), my Linux server is called a *Platform* hosting my Tomcat 6 *Server*, which in turn hosts *Services* (e.g. "Servlet Monitor") that finally expose *Metrics* (e.g. "Error Count per Minute").

I assume I need to develop a custom Hyperic plugin (just an XML file, really) that would point the agent and server at the correct JMX MBeans. Ideally, I would like to see my webapp listed as a Service hosted by the Tomcat 6 Server, but looking at the [Plugin Development docs](http://support.hyperic.com/display/DOC/JMX+Plugin), that doesn't seem to be possible.

Maybe that's not too bad anyway, because in theory, I might want to switch my app to Jetty. But I figure that's a very common use case, so are there any best practices? I couldn't really find any examples of this on the web, so I thought I might just ask the experts..

**Please note:** The Hyperic docs I linked to seem to require an account to view.

Comment: please take a look at this link: http://support.hyperic.com/display/EVO/JMX+Plugin it describes how to integrate a custom JMX implementation into Hyperic. Nco

Comment: Check here: http://support.hyperic.com/display/EVO/JMX+Plugin